# ask import undefined Go

Tags: go

i have problem about import on go lang. How to call package routes and function getRoute(my own function) on golang?

my main package is

```
package main
import(
    "github.com/majalah/apps/routes"
)
func main() {
    routes.getRoute()
}
```

and my routes package inside apps and folder routes

```
package routes

func getRoute() {

}
```

it's always error

```
4.2 imported and not used "routes"
8.2 undefined "routes"
```

Comment: You need to export getRoutes to be able to use it outside of its package. Change getRoutes to GetRoutes. First uppercase letter makes an identifier in Go exported.

Comment: Only capitalized function names are being exported, moreover, show us how you build project.

Comment: wow it's work just capitalized make it wrong?

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers

Comment: Show the project directory structure please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

function start with lower case is an unexport function. An unexport function can be used only inside the package. You have to export getRoute function by changing the function name to **GetRoute**.